# Connect to another ubuntu machine

Tags: networking

I have two Ubuntu computers connected to the same wifi connection in my office.

Neither laptop has had any networking configuration edits, both laptops are essentially "out of the box" installs which to my knowledge have no static IP configured

Given root access to both machines, What is the easiest method to configure and connect via ssh (or perhaps other methods) between both computers?

Comment: From which computer are you trying to connect to these laptops?

Comment: Ideally, given the two computers A & B, I am trying to connect from A to B and B to A

Comment: You're trying to connect them to do what exactly?

Comment: Ok! So whats wrong with ssh? What are your requirements? Transfer files? Use graphic environment?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a "typical" wifi set up it should be running DHCP server, so both of your laptops should get an IP automatically once you connect to wifi. run `ifconfig -a` to confirm that you got an IP and try to ping both boxes from each other. If you can connect to your office WiFi but don't get an IP talk to your network admin and ask for IP.

Once you can ping, ssh is the way to go to connect to boxes `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` read more here https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html